# Simple code explanation

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Is this:

```
$_GET['value'] = isset($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : '';
```

same like this:

```
$_GET['value'] = isset($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : false;
```

?

Or is better do a first ? Is there any more variations of this code?
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It's not the same. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, no.  They're not the same.  One potentially sets the value to an empty string, the other potentially sets the value to `false`.  Why are you setting a value in the `$_GET` collection anyway?  What exactly is this meant to do?

Comment: @Farer When I get  error notice like "Undefined index: value" can I use booth codes or just first example ?

Comment: Side note: depending on what you're using this for, `empty()` may be better than `isset()`. That is unknownst to us. The question for me is unclear in that respect.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner can be "empty()" used for getting session number for example? or referral code number? how to do a code with empty() ?

Comment: `isset()` works best for checkboxes/radios, that's why I mentioned that. If there was already a value set for it somewhere, then that is a point worth being mentioned where `isset()` could fail. The source is unknown until now, sort of.

Comment: @David for getting session or referral code for example.

Comment: Why are you checking for a `value` than setting it if it already exists with the same `value` else placing an empty string or boolean instead? I think this is a better question. Maybe you could look up [ternary operators](http://www.dnawebagency.com/ternary-operator/) to understand them a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. They're not the same thing.

The first will return an empty string if the `value` GET parameter is not set, or return the parameter if it is set.

The second will return false if the parameter is not set.

So you're changing the original `$_GET` array, which is not really a good idea.

An alternative syntax is the null coalesce operator (`??`) that would turn your code into this:

```
$variable = $_GET['value'] ?? ''; //or false, if you want to stick with the boolean.
```

The `??` operator basically runs `isset()` on the left expression and returns the first ocurrence of a truthy expression.

If you need to check for an empty string, you should use `empty` instead of `isset`.

Comment: ok, When use it to get referral code or session number how to use with using "empty" ? Can you write me a code for $variable = $_GET['value'] ?? ''; with using empty ? Thank you for answer anyway!